# QML test fails in Qt 5.9.1

Tags: c++, qt, qttest

While compiling in Qt 5.9.1 version it is not working.. Any one help me to compile this TestCase in qml..

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtTest 1.1

    TestCase{
            function test_math() {
                compare(2 + 2, 4, "2 + 2 = 4")
            }

            function test_fail() {
                compare(2 + 2, 5, "2 + 2 = 5")
            }

        }
```

Getting error like this:

> Type TestCase unavailable and module Qt.test.qtestroot is not installed